# How to setup static IP address on RPi 4 with VNC support

Tags: pi-4, vnc, raspbian-buster, static-ip

I have a RPi 4 running Raspbian buster. I would like to setup a static IP address for it with support for VNC. I have tried a number of tutorials and I have succeded in making a static IP address for my RPi, but then i can't connect to it from my desktop using VNC. I'm using eth0 on my RPi, and both the RPi and my desktop are connected to the same router via LAN cable. Any solutions to this?

Comment: is a VNC server running on the Pi?

Comment: Yes, VNC i running on my RPi using "sudo raspi-config" and the enabling VNC. But i have found a solution to my problem. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My question have been solved following the excellent guide/answer from @Milliways to the question here: [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address/74428#74428). I used the dhcpcd method. Both the static IP address on my RPi 4 and connecting to it from my desktop via VNC is now working.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: Done (y). I had to wait 2 days to do it